# How do you add arguments for the event interactionCreate in discord.js V13

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I recently switched from discord.js V12 to discord.js V13

How do you add arguments to slash commands?
Ex: /verify UsernameHere

I am trying to make a verify system as i am very interested on slash commands.
Any help is appreciated; Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slash commands have options where you can set them up with the following types:

`SUB_COMMAND` sets the option to be a subcommand
`SUB_COMMAND_GROUP` sets the option to be a subcommand group
`STRING` sets the option to require a string value
`INTEGER` sets the option to require an integer value
`NUMBER` sets the option to require a decimal (also known as a floating point) value
`BOOLEAN` sets the option to require a boolean value
`USER` sets the option to require a user or snowflake as value
`CHANNEL` sets the option to require a channel or snowflake as value
`ROLE` sets the option to require a role or snowflake as value
`MENTIONABLE` sets the option to require a user, role or snowflake as value

You can check them out in the [guides option types](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#option-types)

So now to reply to them you will need to parse the option where you can find a detailed explanation at [guides-parsing-options](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#parsing-options)

```js
const string = interaction.options.getString('input');
const integer = interaction.options.getInteger('int');
const number = interaction.options.getNumber('num');
const boolean = interaction.options.getBoolean('choice');
const user = interaction.options.getUser('target');
const member = interaction.options.getMember('target');
const channel = interaction.options.getChannel('destination');
const role = interaction.options.getRole('muted');
const mentionable = interaction.options.getMentionable('mentionable');

console.log([string, integer, boolean, user, member, channel, role, mentionable]);
```

**example of slash command:**

```js
const data = {
  name: "verify", // no uppercase, else you will get an error
  description: "Example description",
  options: [{
    name: "username", // no uppercase as well
    description: "example option description",
    type: "USER"
  }]
}
```

I hope you found this helpful! :)

Comment: If I’m not wrong, I thought `options` was supposed to be an array?

Comment: if it's one option, i guess it can be an obj directly, i didn't really test it though, but imma edit my answer in case it didn't work, thanks for reminding me!

Comment: and this has all changed completely again in discord 14... all the v13 errors make it really hard to search.